# Submitting symfony forms using modals?

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

So i'm using symfony 2.3 as my framework and I have a problem with form submissions.
so here is a form in my controller:

**Controller.php**

```
    public function ImageAction(Request $request)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $imageRepo = $em->getRepository('ImageBundle:Image'); 
    $imageTable = $imageRepo->findAll();

    $image = new Image();
    $imageForm = $this->createForm(new ImageType(), $image);
    $imageForm->handleRequest($request);
    ...
```

this I displayed in the twig:

**View.html.twig**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12">
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            {{form_start(imageForm)}}
                    {{form_widget(imageForm.file, { "attr":{ "onchange": "readURL(this)"} })}}
                    {{form_errors(imageForm.file)}}
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <button data-reveal-id="adminDrop">save default avatar</button>
        </div>
        {{form_end(imageForm)}}
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <img id="default-avatar" style="width:60px;height: 60px;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the modal block

```
     {% block modals %}
     <!-- Modals -->
     <div id="adminDrop" class="reveal-modal large">
     Admin password to complete action<br/>
     <input type = "password", id="pass" />
     <button id = "test">Submit</button>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal", id="close">&#215;</a>
     {%endblock%}
```

so what happens here is that when I hit the "save default avatar" button, a modal will pop up that should prompt for a user password.

what i want to achieve is to create a modal that would prompt for the user password and submit the form from the controller. I have searched the net about this problem and I couldn't find any. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You're talking about adding a password form, but your code shows logic about avatar. What did you try about your password saving ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it to show the modal with an input type password, but it doesn't have any functionality.